# Convert SelectValue to int

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedvalue

I have a project in WinForm where I have a ComboBox. What I want to do is copy the value of the `SelectedValue` property into a variable of type `int`.

```
private void cbIzq_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblNombreIzq.Text = cbIzq.Text;
    int personaId = Int32.Parse(cbIzq.SelectedValue);
    lblEstaturaIzq.Text = GetEstatura(personaId) + " cm";
}

private string GetEstatura(int persona)
{
    return ListaMedidas.Where(x => x.persona == persona).Select(e => e.estatura).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
}
```

But it throws me the error:

> cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

What should I do to solve it?

Comment: What Type is the Property assigned to the `ValueMember`? If it's of Type `int`, then just cast it.

Comment: Adding to @jimi's comment: `int personaId = (int)cbIzq.SelectedValue;`

Comment: ValueMember is type int

Comment: Try the cast but this error appears:
System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversión especificada no es válida.'

Comment: I found the solution by enclosing the cast inside a try block although I'm not sure why it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> See how to use Int32.Parse

[Int32.Parse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-6.0)

> Fixing it with the code below seems to solve the problem.
> `int personaId = Int32.Parse(cbIzq.SelectedValue.ToString())`